# Keras Cant Seem To Configure inputShape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to do the "Hello World" of Keras with Iris-Flowers and I cannot configure the input_shape. This is my error message:

```
"ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (120, 4)"
```

When I change my input_shape to the received input shape, it just changes what it says the received input is. As you know there are 4 inputs and one output with this data set. Does anyone know how I would configure my input_shape?

Here's my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

text_file = open("iris.data.txt")
rawData = text_file.read().split('\n')
text_file.close()

for x in range(0,150):
    rawData[x] = rawData[x].split(',')

xs_train = []
ys_train = []
for i in range (0,40):
    ys_train.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_train.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])
for i in range (50,90):
    ys_train.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_train.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])
for i in range (100,140):
    ys_train.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_train.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])

xs_test = []
ys_test = []
for i in range (40,50):
    ys_test.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_test.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])
for i in range (90,100):
    ys_test.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_test.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])
for i in range (140,150):
    ys_test.append(rawData[i][4])
    xs_test.append([rawData[i][0], rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]])

# print(xs_train)   

for i in range(0, len(ys_train)):
    if ys_train[i] == "Iris-setosa":
        ys_train[i] = [1,0,0]
    if ys_train[i] == "Iris-versicolor":
        ys_train[i] = [0,1,0]
    if ys_train[i] == "Iris-virginica":
        ys_train[i] = [0,0,1]

# print(ys_train)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(1,4), activation= 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xs_train, ys_train, epochs=3)
```

My inputs are formatted so that each array is a dataset, each set including 4 
data points, it goes as so:

```
[['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2'],
 ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2'],
 ['4.7', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2']...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_shape=(4,)
```

Input shape doesn't care for the batch size, only for "each" sample size.

Comment: Nope, when I change input shape to (4,) it give me the error                                                 "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (120, 3)"                                                                                             Which is what confuses my, it says that the array shape has changed

Comment: You changed your last Dense layer. In the question, it's `Dense(3...`, now you're using `Dense(1....` or another layer with size 1.

Comment: model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(4,), activation= 'relu')) This is my line of code... hmmmmm

Comment: "Target" is the output, not the input.

Comment: Ohhhh... This is related to the output, the configuration of the input is fine now. Ok, i think i can get this now